# how to use json file consisting of host info as input to ansible inventory

Tags: ansible-inventory

I am trying to use the following json file as input to ansible host inventory but I get error when I run the playbook.
**JSON File:**

```
{
   "instances":{
       "host": 10.66.70.33
   }
}
```

### Playbook:

> hosts: "{{ instances.host }}"
>   remote_user: root   #vars:

When I run the play book I get the following errors. I am not sure where I am doing wrong. I am new to Ansible. Please advice I guess i am doing some silly mistake.

> [WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: all 
>   [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available
>   ERROR! The field 'hosts' has an invalid value, which includes an
>   undefined variable. The error was: 'instances' is undefined

**I am running the playbook as follows:**

```
ansible-playbook -i <path>/test.json <path>test_playbook.yml
```

Answer (score 8):

Ansible's [yaml plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/inventory/yaml.html) **will** actually parse a JSON file, and has done so for years.

It's barely documented but you can see in the [parameters section of the yaml plugin docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/inventory/yaml.html#parameters), `.json` is listed as a valid extension.

The JSON format has the same *semantics* as the YAML format. Note: *not* the same format as the [dynamic inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_inventory.html#developing-inventory-scripts)!

So your JSON should look like,

```
{
   "instances": {
      "hosts": {
         "10.66.70.33": null
      }
   }
}
```

Note: it's "hosts" rather than "host" and each address is a dictionary/hash key with the values being host-specific vars.

Taking the first example from [Working with Inventory docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#inventory-basics-hosts-and-groups),

```
all:
  hosts:
    mail.example.com:
  children:
    webservers:
      hosts:
        foo.example.com:
        bar.example.com:
    dbservers:
      hosts:
        one.example.com:
        two.example.com:
        three.example.com:
```

would look like,

```
{
  "all": {
    "hosts": {
      "mail.example.com": null
    },
    "children": {
      "webservers": {
        "hosts": {
          "foo.example.com": null,
          "bar.example.com": null
        }
      },
      "dbservers": {
        "hosts": {
          "one.example.com": null,
          "two.example.com": null,
          "three.example.com": null
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Those `null`s are odd-looking but in the YAML example you'll see the trailing colon which does indeed mean each of those hosts are effectively dictionary/hash keys.

For the curious, the JSON-then-YAML loading code is in [parsing/utils/yaml.py](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-2.9/lib/ansible/parsing/utils/yaml.py#L68) and the actual parsing is in [parsing/inventory/yaml.py](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-2.9/lib/ansible/plugins/inventory/yaml.py#L96).

Comment: Talk about non-obvious!! Thanks for exposing/documenting this functionality

Answer (score 3):

It seems pure JSON it's not supported as inventory file. In the [inventory plugin list](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/plugins/inventory.html) I don't see JSON:

> - advanced_host_list - Parses a ‘host list’ with ranges
> - auto - Loads and executes an inventory plugin specified in a YAML config
> - aws_ec2 - ec2 inventory source
> - constructed - Uses Jinja2 to construct vars and
>     groups based on existing inventory.
> - host_list - Parses a ‘host list’
>     string
> - ini - Uses an Ansible INI file as inventory source.
> - k8s - Kubernetes (K8s) inventory source
> - openshift - OpenShift inventory
>     source
> - openstack - OpenStack inventory source
> - script - Executes an
>     inventory script that returns JSON
> - virtualbox - virtualbox inventory
>     source
> - yaml - Uses a specifically YAML file as inventory source.

On the other hand you can wrap that JSON in a simple python script as follows:

1. Make sure the script plugin is enabled in your `ansible.cfg` file:

   ```
   [inventory]
   enable_plugins = host_list, script, yaml, ini
   ```
2. Create wrapper script (inventory file), only reads your JSON and prints it in the console (I'm assuming the JSON and the wrapper script are in the same path):

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env python
   import os

   __location__ = os.path.realpath(
       os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.dirname(__file__)))

   with open(os.path.join(__location__, "hosts.json")) as f:
       print f.read()
   ```
3. Use the following in your JSON inventory ([performance improvements](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_inventory.html)):

   ```
   {
       "_meta": {
           "hostvars": { }
       },

       "instances": {
           "hosts": ["10.66.70.33"]
       }
   }
   ```
4. When running the playbook just be aware the group you want to target should be "instances", for example this is my playbook:

   ```
   ---
   - hosts: instances
     tasks:
       - debug:
           msg: Hi there
   ```

Then just run the playbook as you did, specifying the python wrapper script, in my case this was:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory/hostswrapper.py test-stkovfl.yml
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: As mentioned before JSON does actually parse as YAML, i.e. a YAML-parser can read both formats.

Comment: For anyone wondering about the obviousness of this, JSON *is* (a subset of) YAML.  
If you have valid JSON, it is also valid YAML.

Comment: A simple shell script with `cat hosts.json` will suffice, no need to complicate this with Python

Answer (score 2):

late but i hope this could help you !

I took this info from [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_inventory.html)

---

Json inventory is almost exactly as Yaml inventory. You should keep in mind these json keys:

- hosts: json **array** to define your host**s**. *Notice the plural*
- vars: json object to define vars with its values at **group level**
- children: allows you to define an inner hostgroup
- _meta: to define metadata like host specific variables

for example:

```json
{
  "all": {                                               # group called `all`
    "hosts": ["webmin.mydomain.com"],                    # hosts that compose `all` group
    "vars": {                                            # vars for `all` hosts
      "vendor": "vultr"                                  # var definition called `vendor`
    },
    "children": {                                        # inner group definition 
      "ipc": {                                           # called `ipc` ...
        "hosts": ["ipc-appserver-01", "ipc-db-01"],      # hosts that compose `ipc` group
        "vars": {                                        # vars only for `ipc` hosts
          "os": "centos7.6"                              # var def for `ipc` group called `os`
        }
      }                                                  # you could define more inner host groups
    }
  },
  "_meta": {                                             # metadata
    "hostvars": {                                        
      "ipc-appserver-01": {                              # vars only for `ipc-appserver-01` host
        "role": "php"                                    # var called `role`
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You cannot pass this json to `ansible-playbook -i` it will not work. Have you actually tried it?