# Ansible inventory script requires requests module, how do I install packages to Ansible itself?

Tags: python, ansible, ansible-inventory

I am using a python script which pull from a rest api and then builds and prints out an inventory in JSON. very similar to the question here [how to use json file consisting of host info as input to ansible inventory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48680425/how-to-use-json-file-consisting-of-host-info-as-input-to-ansible-inventory)

however my script requires requests to pull the data from the rest api, but it doesnt look like Ansible has the package?

```
ansible-playbook -i host_wrapper.py gather_ios_facts.yml -k -vvv
...
/Users/alexw/ansible/host_wrapper.py did not meet yaml requirements, check plugin documentation if this is unexpected
 [WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /Users/alexw/ansible/host_wrapper.py with script plugin: Inventory script
(/Users/alexw/ansible/host_wrapper.py) had an execution error: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/Users/alexw/ansible/host_wrapper.py", line 2, in <module>     import requests, json ImportError: No module named
requests

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/plugins/inventory/script.py", line 114, in parse
    raise AnsibleError("Inventory script (%s) had an execution error: %s " % (path, err))
```

the first lines in my host_wrapper script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import requests, json
...
```

EDIT:

I assumed that I would just install it with pip however it still fails, output below:

```
AW-MacBook-Pro:ansible alexw$ pip install reqeusts
Collecting reqeusts
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement reqeusts (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for reqeusts
You are using pip version 19.0.2, however version 19.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
AW-MacBook-Pro:ansible alexw$ pip install requests
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (2.21.0)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests) (2018.11.29)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.25,>=1.21.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests) (1.24.1)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests) (2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests) (3.0.4)
You are using pip version 19.0.2, however version 19.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

AW-MacBook-Pro:ansible alexw$ ansible-playbook -i host_wrapper.py gather_ios_facts.yml -k -vvv
ansible-playbook 2.7.7
  config file = /Users/alexw/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/Users/alexw/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 3.6.4 (default, Mar 22 2018, 13:54:22) [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)]
Using /Users/alexw/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
SSH password:
/Users/alexw/ansible/host_wrapper.py did not meet host_list requirements, check plugin documentation if this is unexpected
/Users/alexw/ansible/host_wrapper.py did not meet yaml requirements, check plugin documentation if this is unexpected
 [WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /Users/alexw/ansible/host_wrapper.py with script plugin: Inventory script
(/Users/alexw/ansible/host_wrapper.py) had an execution error: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/Users/alexw/ansible/host_wrapper.py", line 2, in <module>     import requests, json ImportError: No module named
requests
```

Comment: pip install requests

Comment: hi, I did think that, however it still outputs the same

Comment: also when I run the python script just on its own from the same folder it works, just not when attached to an Ansible playbook command

Answer (score -1):

it turns out my shebang pointed to python 2.7 which didn't have the module installed. my local python command was set to run 3.6 by default.

ammended my shebang to point to 3.6 and it now import correctly

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.6
import requests, json
```